# Windows Phone App Freezing while loading main page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

My windows phone app is freezing while loading the main page. I have set breakpoints on the main contructor and it fires the OnNavigatedTo event but never fires the "Loaded" event. It gets through the InitializeComponent() in the contructor. It shows the splash screen and the mainpage application bar, but freezes at that point.

I have recently refactored my main namespace, which was causing the mainpage to not load. I fixed that via the Startup Object.

EVERYTHING was working before the refactoring.

What code should I include? The project is fairly large at this point, so I dont know how much you really want me posting code.

Any ideas??

Comment: Can you go back to before your refactoring, redo to whole thing one bit at a time until your project breaks? Or can you reverse it bit by bit until it works? Or would that take too long?

Comment: Are you getting an exception, or is it just hanging indefinitely? Are you in the emulator or on a device?

Comment: And maybe include your XAML file :)

Comment: @user643192 I have done that. It's under version control. After re-resolving some dependencies, it does run and compile. I did some resharper code cleanup and refactored my startup project namespace. Doing what you suggested is how I narrowed it down to the namespace refactoring.

Comment: Glad you found the error. Rolling back to a previous version is a real pain in the backside, but at least you got it fixed. Imagine what it would have been if it still didn't work after doing all that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. In App.Xaml.cs I made the following crucial mistake:

Here is my code:

```
private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
        if (RootVisual != null && RootVisual != RootFrame)
            RootVisual = RootFrame;

        // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
        RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
    }
```

And here is what is was supposed to be:

```
    private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
        if (RootVisual != RootFrame)
            RootVisual = RootFrame;

        // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
        RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
    }
```

Resharper thought it would be best to check if RootVisual was null first. Incredibly irritating mistake as It would just hang at the startup PNG and never load, obviously because RootVisual wasn't being set.

Comment: Wow !!! That is indeed an interesting catch. Thanks for sharing. [BTW.. Always use Source Control or some other backup before you proceed to refactor. Better Safe than Worry;-) ]

Comment: I am using SVN which is how i found it. by going back through 6 revisions and running it until I found one that worked. That revision touched almost every file in the solution and I had to go through each one and SVN Diff it between that and the revision up where it didnt work and test each change to see what caused it. Extremely frustrating and basically lost 2 entire days of work just to fix that one mistake. Sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

I've had difficulties like this before. Sounds like it's probably a problem in your XAML but without actually having your solution it's hard to tell.

Here's a couple of things you could try:

- Check all your static/dynamic resources to make sure that they're all still resolving correctly.
- Check that any bindings and binding converters that you're using are still resolving properly. Converters in particular, I've had issues with them in the past.

If you're getting exceptions, but not tied to a specific point in code:

- Try putting breakpoints on any or all custom properties that you might be using. Properties aren't stepped into by the debugger by default. I've found this to be the cause of a number of exceptions in my own work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, it is not throwing exceptions. after hitting the main constructor in my MainPage code behind and hitting the OnNavigatedTo Event it just hangs. If i pause the debugger I can see its not in my code.